# Auxiliary Verbs (Do,Does,Did)

Tags: grammar

I had done some researched online, but i can't find any answer to this question.

1) Can Auxiliary Verb "do/does/did" take present tense after it?

2) Is the auxiliary verb "have/has/had" only take past participle?

Comment: Auxiliary _do_ takes an infinitive (same as present tense form, but no suffix) after it.  Auxiliary _have_ plus a past participle is the Perfect construction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auxiliary *DO* always takes a following **infinitive**. With every verb except *BE* the infinitive form is identical with the 'plain' form used for the simple present. (With *BE* the infinitive form is *be*; but of course *DO* is not followed by a form of *BE* except in non-standard dialects.)

Auxiliary *HAVE* always takes a following **past participle**, forming the perfect construction.